# How can I call a method when activity loads without doing nothing in android studio?

Tags: android

this is my first question here on Stackoverflow.
I'm trying to call the method in my code below just when the Activity starts, but it's not be called. When I press a button, imageview, etc inside the same activity the method is called successfully. Why does it not get called when the activity first loads?

```
public class TablaComentarios extends AppCompatActivity {
  ImageView send_comment;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabla_comentarios);
  send_comment=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mandar_mensaje);

  send_comment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
     @Override
      public void onClick(View v){
      }
  }

  public void subscribe(){
  }    
}
```

Comment: looks like you forgot code part in your question !

Comment: which method are you trying to call ? Here, you're not calling any methods...

Answer (score 0):

Call the function at the end of your `onCreate`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    .. other code
    subscribe();
}
```

Comment: PLEASE PRESS F5 TO REREHSH I'D FORGOTTEN THE CODE

Comment: yes I have code for subscribe ,it's a litte Toast but I didn't publish it because I only wanted tot know why this didn't work

Comment: You have to call the function in the oncreate. The function won't be called otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TablaComentarios extends AppCompatActivity {  

    ImageView send_comment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabla_comentarios);
       //Call your method here
       subscribe():
       send_comment=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mandar_mensaje);

       send_comment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v){
             //IF I CALL THE METHOD HERE, ITS CALLED
            }
    }//END ONCREATE

    public void subscribir(){
    }
}
```

This is because you are calling in button event, try this code.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by other answer, you implemented your method `subscribe()` but never called it.
To have it run on `Activity` creation, just call it from within `onCreate` block !

Answer (score 0):

**Call the method inside onCreate()** method inside your activity class .